# How to add comment in apache httpd.conf not as a complete line?

Tags: apache, comments, httpd.conf

In an apache conf file, if a line is start with `#`, that line is counted as comment. For example,

```
#This is a comment line
#And then the following is some real settings:
AllowOverride None
```

However, this is not allowed.

```
#And then the following is some real settings:
AllowOverride None #A comment that starts in the middle of line
```

Is it possible to starts a comment in the middle of the line? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#syntax) states that it is not possible:

> ... Lines that begin with the hash character "#" are considered comments,
>   and are ignored. Comments may **not** be included on the same line as a
>   configuration directive ...

Comment: I wonder... can a comment be indented? As in, if the hash character is preceded by whitespace, is this still considered to be a "line that begins with the hash character"?

Comment: @osullic yes it can be indented.

Answer (score 4):

I believe only `#` is parsed as there is no real need for it. But if you really need you can use `IfDefine` block, which will be ignored unless a matching variable has a definition.

```
<IfDefine myexisterenceIsForJustAComment>
...
</IfDefine>
```

Look at discussion at : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1349546

Not sure if these are supported in latest versions (< httpd-2.2.15-53) but you can try below which was supported in earlier versions. You may be in luck if you are on older version.

In earlier/older versions of Apache, I remember it was okay to include a comment at the end of a line (wrapped in double quotation marks), like so:

```
<Limit GET >
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx "# I am in inline comment"
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache interprets its conf files line by line. And it considers a line starting with `#` as a blank line (or line break) and skips the line.
Also it doesn't have a symbol to indicate comments because conf files have many special symbols, which might let them to disable middle-line comment.